# Prestashop module debugging

Tags: php, prestashop

I am newbie in Prestashop module development so sorry if it is a fool question... I have been reading the docs but I haven't found what I am looking for so here I go,

I'd like to show a message on the screen (just for debugging purpose) with different context vars and so forth when actionCartSave. Something similar to "console.log()" or "alert()" in js.

Impossible to add the product to the cart.

*textStatus: 'parsererror'*

*errorThrown: 'SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<''*

*responseText:*

< xmp style="text-align: left;" > message: < /xmp>

*{

*"products"*: [...] *

I have already test this code:

```
public function hookActionCartSave( $params )
{
     ppp('message: ');
     return true;
}
```

...inside the module class definition but I am getting this error when I add a product to the cart:

I get this text in a different browser window.

So please, what is the best way to go?

Hope everything is clear. Thanks.

Comment: prestashop 1.7: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/configuration/#using-the-dump-method

Comment: currently trying to do similar thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct, this error message is something thrown by javascript running in your browser since the additional information you are printing out using `ppp` isn't valid JSON.

If you use Chrome, use developer tools and select the Network tab.  You will see the ajax call here.  You can inspect this call in more detail by clicking on it.

Comment: Ok Damon, I see if I use  `ppp(WELL_FORMED_JSON_HERE);` I get: "<xmp style="text-align: left;">{"message": "Well formed JSON message here"}</xmp><br />". But it keeps on saying "Impossible to add the product to the cart." I gess that is the correct behavior when debugging... right?

Comment: ppp is an alias of Tools::p which calls Tools::dieObject.  The additional code you've printed is echo'd out by that function.  You would be better off using just die(json_encode(array("message", "whatever")));

Comment: Damon thank you very much. It is much better this way (with die) as the other window is no scrollable when the text is too long. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best option, but I found it useful to debug with a simple

```
throw new Exception('Custom message ' . $someVariable);
```